# Properties of expectation on matrices

Tags: probability, matrices, expectation

Suppose $X$, $Y$ are matrices of random variables, which are independent and $A$ is matrix of numbers.

Are the below statements correct?

- $E[X^TAX]=E[X^T]AE[X]$
- $E[X^TYX]=E[X^T]E[Y]E[X]$

in which $E[.]$ means the expectation value of matrix.

Comment: Try comparing the two sides elementwise

Answer (score 3):

No, even when the matrices have size one. In general, it is not true that for a random variable $X$, we have $\mathbb E\left[X^2\right]=\left(\mathbb E\left[X\right]\right)^2$, which is what would give the suggested formulas.